# Django ) 'authenticate' with the user model retrieved by the foreign model

Tags: django, django-authentication, one-to-one, django-users

I'm developing 'email verification' module.

First of all, I have a model named 'SNUser' having 'One To One' relationship with the default 'user' model below :

```
class SNUser(models.Model):
# Manager
    objects = SNUserManager()

# Auth
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

I finished sending email containing the unique token for an user.

When the link is clicked, I searched the correct SNUser object  by the token.(That token is one of the field of SNUser model).

So what I want to develop is that when that token link is clicked, the correct user could use the service without login.

So when that link is clicked, 'login(request,user)' should be done.

I already tried two ways to solve this.

1. when I retrieved the user model from SNUser model and did 'login(request, user)' directly :

   > snuser = SNUser.objects.get(token=key)
   >
   > user = snuser.user
   >
   > login(request, user)
   >   It results with the error : Anonymous User.
2. After retrieving the default user from SNUser model, I did 'authenticate(username=user.username, password=user.password)'.
   But many of you already notice, user.password is the hashed not the rawone. So it fails again.

My goal is to retrieve the user from the token included in the link I sent and make him/her use the service without login module as many services follow this process.

Is there anyway to solve this one?

Thank you!

**** UPDATE ****

**I created the custom backend not requiring raw password for my situation below :**

```
class SNUserEmailVerificationAuthBackend(ModelBackend):

def authenticate(self, username=None, email=None):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(username=username, email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, username):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

The updated critical code in views.py is below :

```
            snuser.is_email_verified = True
            snuser.save()
            user = snuser.user
            manager=SNUserEmailVerificationAuthBackend()
            new_user=manager.authenticate(username=user.username,email=user.email)
            login(request,new_user)
```

> login(request,new_user)
>
> Above line is working(it means user suceeds in loggin in) but raising the error simultaneously : 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

****REMOVE DUPLICATED MARK****

Comment: How did you import `login`? Where did you get the error? Please show the full traceback.

Comment: I used django built-in library 'from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login'

Comment: @Alasdair I updated

Comment: @Alasdair this is not a duplicate question. The other question refers to some Open edX-specific code.

Comment: @RégisB. I didn't close the question as a duplicate. Burhan did.

Comment: Sorry about that. cc @burhan-khalid

Comment: @RégisB. Actually, login(request,new_user) is done raising an error : 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'', I will update again to describe my situation

Comment: I can't add a new answer to this question while it's marked as duplicate, so I'll just give an answer here. Just get rid of your authentication backend and define the setting: `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS  = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend']`.
Then just login with `login(request, user)`.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved with 'user.backend=None'.

I refered to [authenticate function in django using hashed password not the raw one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099303/authenticate-function-in-django-using-hashed-password-not-the-raw-one)

I wish it would be helpful for anyone refering this post.

Comment: And it causes the clouse of the session when the current page is routed to anywhere...

Comment: The immediate closure of session is solved by custom backend.